# Incorrect weather in OpenWeatherMap

Tags: python, telegram-bot, openweathermap

OpenWeatherMap displays incorrect weather, help to find the error.

My code should output the weather in the telegram bot for every three hours of today, but it outputs incorrect data from OpenWeatherMap. For example, it's 18 o'clock and the weather is 32 degrees, and he outputs 16 degrees in the weather by the clock. Although the weather is displayed above at the moment and 32 degrees is displayed!

Weather output at the moment:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_weather(message):
    global last_city
    city = message.text if message.text else last_city
    url = f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid={API_KEY}&units=metric'


    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()

        weather = round(data['main']['temp'])
        desc = data['weather'][0]['description']

        forecast_url = f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q={city}&appid={API_KEY}&units=metric'
        forecast_response = requests.get(forecast_url)
        forecast_data = forecast_response.json()

        wind_speed = data['wind']['speed']
        humidity = data['main']['humidity']
        pressure = data['main']['pressure']
        visibility = data['visibility']

bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         f"Now in the city {city}: \n Temperature: {weather}°C\n{description}\n\n Additional parameters:\n Wind speed: {wind_speed} m/s \n Humidity: {humidity}%\n Pressure: {pressure} hPa\n Visibility: {visibility} м\n\n{advice}\n")
```

Weather output by the clock

```
forecast = "\n Weather forecast for today:\n"

        for i in range(0, 25, 3):
            desc = forecast_data['list'][i]['weather'][0]['description']
            desc_rus = weather_desc_dict.get(desc, desc)

            forecast += f"{i}:00 - {desc_rus}, temperature{round(forecast_data['list'][i]['main']['temp'])}°C\n"

        if 'rain' in forecast.lower():
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "⚠️ Attention, rain is expected today!")
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, forecast)
```

Comment: Where do you define and create `weather_desc_dict`. Your error appears to be there because you use that value to display the forecast, but you both look for and define a default value that are the same...this seems off: `desc_rus = weather_desc_dict.get(desc, desc)` as `desc` will be the value no matter what